# Upgrade Titan DB from 0.4.4 to 0.5.x

Tags: cassandra, titan, gremlin

I was assigned a task to migrate our Titan DB from 0.4.4 to 0.5.x with Cassandra as backend. I must admit I underestimated the effort.:-) Here is  question:

Titan 0.4.4 has `system_auth keyspace` while Titan 0.5.4 doesn't have that. I can use `AllowAllAuthorize` to login Cassandra without problem. Just be curious this difference is because of  Titan or Cassandra?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Asking multiple questions at once is usually discouraged. If you have multiple questions please ask these separately.

Comment: sure, I will split question next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`system_auth` is a Cassandra keyspace, not something Titan specific.

Check out the Cassandra security documentation here http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/security_config_native_authenticate_t.html

Comment: When you restart Cassandra with `PasswordAuthenticator`, the `system_auth` keyspace appears.